Spring SwitchUserFilter sees no existing authentication
I’ve got the whole impersonation setup: filter, authentication, the works. This is a Vaadin application based on SpringBoot.
    @Bean
    public SwitchUserFilter switchUserFilter() {
        SwitchUserFilter filter = new SwitchUserFilter();
        filter.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        filter.setSwitchUserMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/impersonate", "GET"));
        filter.setExitUserUrl("/impersonate/logout");
        filter.setTargetUrl("/");
        return filter;
    }

As I understand this, after a regular login of administrator, a manually typed impersonate URL should correctly do an impersonation. But of course it does not.
I see the execution enter SwitchUserFilter, the URL matches, and it attempts to do an impersonation (createSwitchUserToken). But then Spring’s ThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy thinks there is no current user logged in, because its contextHolder contains null. That gets then populated with an EmptyContext, and the user switching fails in SwitchUserGrantedAuthority because of null checks.
Why is the context null?

Sounds like issue might be related to the security context not being properly populated before the impersonation attempt.
Can you please try any of below approaches to resolve the issue:

Is Security Context Populated properly? Make sure that the security context is properly populated with the authenticated user before attempting impersonation. To ensure the same, check if authentication process is correctly setting the security context.

Verify the order of security filters - The order of security filters is crucial. Please ensure that the SwitchUserFilter is placed after the authentication filter in the filter chain.

Check your custom security configuration - Ensure that your security configuration is correctly set up to allow for impersonation.


Here is an example configuration for point 3:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/impersonate", "/impersonate/logout").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .addFilterAfter(switchUserFilter(), SwitchUserFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public SwitchUserFilter switchUserFilter() {
        SwitchUserFilter filter = new SwitchUserFilter();
        filter.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        filter.setSwitchUserMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/impersonate", "GET"));
        filter.setExitUserUrl("/impersonate/logout");
        filter.setTargetUrl("/");
        return filter;
    }
}


Try debugging the Context - Instead of debugging filter, you should also try debugging security context. Add some logs or breakpoints to check the state of the security context before and after the impersonation attempt.

Ensure that authentication is working properly - Verify that the administrator user is properly authenticated and that the security context contains the correct authentication object before attempting impersonation.

Cross verify your Spring Security Version in case none of the above works - Ensure that you are using a compatible version of Spring Security that supports the SwitchUserFilter.


Thank you! Kindly notify me if it works for you :)

I had already filed an issue with Vaadin (https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/20495) after  analysis of the security context. I tried your suggested change (addFilterAfter): it does not work (as expected), because adding another instance of the same filter after the one that was autoconfigured does not make much sense. Because of this obvious illogical step: was the suggestion generated by AI? Other permutations of the same idea do not work either.

That's great to know that issue has been filed. Hope you find the fix soon! Please notify here once resolution is provided.
